# How replace hyperlink of src in img tag with List (hyperlink)

Tags: regex, replace

Ex:

```
String data="<a href="#"><img src="https://i-vnexpress.vnecdn.net/2017/11/12/avangTp-1510462756-4342-1510462774_300x180.jpg"></a>akdjkasj<a href="#"><img src="https://i-vnexpress.vnecdn.net/2017/11/12/avantrumtiphchtch-1510458121-6358-1510458150_300x180.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="https://i-vnexpress.vnecdn.net/2017/11/12/23584171-515769268787265-1654747046-o-1510464027_680x0.jpg"></a>"

List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

with data of list:{"http://link 1","http://link 2","http://link 3"}
How replace hyperlink in src become:

```
data="<a href="#"><img src="http://link 1"></a>akdjkasj<a href="#"><img src="http://link 2"></a><a href="#"><img src="http://link 3"></a>"
```

I already used code code after:

```
public String replace(String str, List<String> arr){
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile( "(?m)(?s)<img\\s+(.*)src\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"(.*)" );
    Matcher m=pattern.matcher(str);
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    int i=0;
    while (m.find()){
       String s1= m.group(0).replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(m.group(2)), list.get(i++));
        m.appendReplacement(sb,s1);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And this result:

```
data="<a href="#"><img src="http://link 1"></a>akdjkasj<a href="#"><img src="https://i-vnexpress.vnecdn.net/2017/11/12/avantrumtiphchtch-1510458121-6358-1510458150_300x180.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="https://i-vnexpress.vnecdn.net/2017/11/12/23584171-515769268787265-1654747046-o-1510464027_680x0.jpg"></a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your goal fully...

Try like this https://regex101.com/r/sCNEVO/2

```
<img.+?src\s?=\s?"(.+?)".+?>
```